# Actualizar Entity Data Model en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf, ado.net, datagrid

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy creando una aplicación de escritorio en WPF con el siguiente planteamiento.

Cuando un usuario se loguea indica su usuario, su contraseña y un grupo al que pertenece. Cuando se inicia la aplicación me debe de aparecer una tabla (la cual tengo implementada mediante un DataGrid) que, dependiendo del grupo que yo haya seleccionado al principio, me mostrará unos datos u otros.

Supongamos que existen los grupos A, B y C y que en la base de datos, cada uno de estos grupos tienen varias tablas, pero todas tienen una que se llama "Elemento", por lo que existiría A.Elemento, B.Elemento y C.Elemento.

He añadido un objeto ADO.NET Entity Data Model mediante el cual me conecto a mi base de datos, que se encuentra en un SQL Server, y no tengo ningún problema en añadirle la tabla A.Elemento en la configuración para luego pasársela al DataGrid de forma manual.

Una vez creado el ADO.NET Entity Data Model, añado un DataSource para conectarselo a través del ContextType y en su colección de vistas (ViewSources) añado las tablas que que quiero que puedan ser enlazadas por un DataGrid o cualquier otro objeto:

```
<c1:C1DataSource x:Name="c1DataSource1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="528,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" ContextType="{x:Type local:EntidadSV2}">
        <c1:EntityViewSource EntitySetName="XElemento"/>
</c1:C1DataSource>
```

Después enlazo el DataGrid con dicho DataSource indicándole, a través de su ItemsSource, qué vista es la que quiero cargar de las que tiene disponibles:

```
<c1:C1DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,131,0,0" CanUserEditRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding [XElemento], ElementName=c1DataSource1}" FrozenTopRowsCount = "1" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"\>
```

El problema está en que no es así como tiene que funcionar, sino que, cuando yo arranque la aplicación, el Data Model deberá de cargar una tabla u otra en función del grupo seleccionado en el login.

¿Alguién sabe cómo puedo actualizar o generar dicho Data Model en tiempo de ejecución indicándole la cadena de conexión y demás?

---

Ejemplo de las entidades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Me temo que tu pregunta carece de información básica para poder ayudarte. Necesitaríamos, por ejemplo, ver algo de código (como está generado el datamodel, el código en el que cargas el DataGrid,etc...). En definitiva, ahora estamos un poco a ciegas, y la pregunta corre el peligro de ser puesta en espera hasta que proporciones algo mas de información. Pásate por [ask] y por el [tour]

Comment: Bueno, en mi caso yo no estoy muy acostumbrado a trabajar con Entity Framework (siempre suelo usar mi propio modelo).De todas maneras, yo creo que por código podrías cambiar el datasource para que apunte a la entidad que necesites...tendría que ver mucho mas código para hacerme una idea. Espero que alguien mas pueda ayudarte :)

Comment: @Pikoh La cosa es que no tengo el código de cómo se crea el Entity Data Model, ya que yo lo añado a mi proyecto y lo voy configurando a través de las ventanas que me van apareciendo indicándole a qué servidor me conecto, la base de datos a la que voy a acceder y las tablas que quiero obtener de dicha base de datos. Al terminar de añadir el entity se genera un archivo .edmx que contiene las entidades a las tablas seleccionadas, en mi caso las siguientes [imagen](https://ibb.co/d0SCx5). La cosa está en que ese procedimiento lo hago manualmente y yo lo necesito hacer a través de código.

Comment: Si, ya te entendí. Por eso te decía, que yo siempre genero todo manualmente, con lo que no se exactamente como solucionarlo ya que no uso nunca Entity Framework. Por aqui seguro que hay alguien que te sepa ayudar mejor que yo ;)

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias de todas formas ^^

Comment: Si estás usando EntityModel o DatabaseFirst, esto hace que se genere código a partir del diagrama de entidades generado, actualizar en runtime creo que no es posible.
Son las limitaciones de Entity, como mencionan arriba, una posibilidad es hacer manual tu modelo, usando entity la verdad no sabría alguna solución.

Comment: El problema esta en que no deberias tener un modelo por usuario.. si no un solo modelo que permitiera entrar a todos los usuarios.. Tu diseño de clases deberia ser lo suficientemente complejo para soportar eso

Comment: @gbianchi te refieres a referenciar todas las tablas de la base de datos en el entity y ya luego, dependiendo del usuario, que cojan una u otra?

Comment: Eso deberias hacer. No deberias tener un modelo por grupo

Comment: De alguna forma me estas queriendo decir que no comparten ni un dato entre cada grupo?

Comment: @gbianchi Tienen en común el nombre de varias tablas, por ejemplo en cada grupo hay una tabla que se llama Elemento, pero dependiendo del grupo contiene unos datos u otros.

Comment: Vale, he conseguido cambiar la cadena de conexión del Entity a través de su propiedad **Database.Connection.ConnectionString**. Ej:  
`entity.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BD1,9999;Initial Catalog=Catalogo2;User ID=user1;pwd=password"`  
De esta manera, si antes mi DataGrid tenía conectado su ItemsSource a la tabla Elemento de la anterior conexión, si yo ahora la actualizo:  
`dataGrid.ItemsSource = entity.Elemento.ToList();`  
Me salen los elementos de la tabla que contiene la nueva conexión.

Comment: Actualizo, aunque la tabla se llame igual en un grupo y en otro, si no contiene las mismas columnas que la se instanció en la entidad (tiene una o varias columnas menos), da error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es cambiar la conexión del **Modelo de Datos de Entity Framework** esto te puede servir:

Creé un método que retorna el **Modelo de Datos** y recibe como parámetro el servidor, la base de datos, el usuario del server, la contraseña del server.

```
ModelDatos bd;
  public ModelDatos ConectaConeccionString(string Servidor, string BaseDatos, string UsuarioSql, string ContraseñaSql)
    {
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder conectar = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        conectar.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        conectar.ProviderConnectionString = string.Format("data source={0};initial catalog={1};user id={2};password={3};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework", Servidor, BaseDatos, UsuarioSql, ContraseñaSql);
        conectar.Metadata = "res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl";
        return bd = new ModelDatos(conectar.ToString());
    }
```

En la clase que te genera el Modelo de Datos hay que crear una sobrecarga al constructor de esta manera para pasar la nueva conexión:

```
public ModelDatos(string Coneccion) : base(Coneccion)
{            
}
```

Un ejemplo de una consulta con esta conección:

```
 public IEnumerable CargaDatos(ModelDatos bd)
        {
            IEnumerable query="";
                query = (from aa in bd.Tabla
                         select aa).ToList();
            return query;
        }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos